# Jasper report OutofMemory issue

Tags: java, jasper-reports, out-of-memory

I am trying to generate Excel report by fetching data from DB and passing the pojo collection list to JRBeanCollectionDataSource. Trying to generate excel with 5000 records with 8 fields getting outofmemory issue.

I tried **JRFileVirtualizer** But no luck, can any one help me to get rid of this OutOfMemory issue. Below is my code

```
public class JasperReport  {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        DBtoExcelDownloadDAO d = new DBtoExcelDownloadDAO();
        List<ExcelDownloadPojo>  results=d.getDBrecordsForDownload(168);

        net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                   .compileReport("C:\\Users\\vkode200\\Networksolve_Report.jrxml");

        String outputFileName = "C:\\Users\\vkode200\\Downloads\\Output\\person.xls";
        JRFileVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRFileVirtualizer(1, "C:\\Users\\vkode200\\Reports");
      JasperPrint  jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, (Map) getParameters(virtualizer),
                new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
                        findReportData(results),false));
        JRXlsExporter exporterXls = new JRXlsExporter();

        exporterXls.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        exporterXls.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outputFileName);

exporterXls.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_AUTO_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporterXls.exportReport();
    }

    private static Collection findReportData(List<ExcelDownloadPojo> results) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        List<JasperPojo> list = SampleExcel.generateExcel(results);
        return list;
    }

    private static Object getParameters(JRFileVirtualizer virtualizer ) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("footerText", "Just to demonstrate how to pass parameters to report");
        params.put("Title", "NETWORK_SOLVE");
        params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER,virtualizer);
        return params;
    }
}
```

---

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getBytes(HSSFWork‌​book.java:1393) at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkboo‌​k.java:1292)

Comment: The most scalable solution is never to hold everything in memory. Eg use `Iterator` and `InputStream` / `OutputStream` so that you've never got everything in memory. This simple / dumb solution is to increase the memory for the JVM via `-x` arguments

Comment: `List<JasperPojo> list = xxx()` is bad, everything is in memory, can you return a stream/iterator instead? I'm not sure if all the technologies you are using support streaming. I'm not going to do your work for you

Comment: I am using JRBeanCollectionDataSource provided by jasper. Which will accept only collection  type. I think JSPER not support to pass data as stream.

Comment: Under the hood, I'm guessing the data is coming from a `ResultSet` which is a stream. Perhaps there's a `DataSource` implementation which accepts a `ResultSet`. Or perhaps you could create some sort of `BeanSource` from the `ResultSet` which you pass to another implementation of `DataSource` rather than using `JRBeanCollectionDataSource `

Comment: As a side note, use the `.jasper` file instead of the `.jrxml` file -- the report will be generated faster without having to compile the `.jasper` file each time.

Comment: I think JRResultSetDataSource - for resultset ; For Bean  JRBeanArrayDataSource and JRBeanCollectionDataSource   is there any Suitable implementation Of DataSource for Beans please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't reduce the amount of data then you should increase the allocated heap for your application to prevent the exception. Since I don't know how your application works, here are some ways to solve this problem:

---

### Command

It is possible to increase heap size allocated to the JVM by using command line options

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size

java -Xms256m -Xmx2048m ClassName
```

---

### NetBeans

Right click on project -> Properties -> Run

[image: Project properties]

---

### Tomcat

`setenv.sh` or `setenv.bat` is executed on startup. Create the file if it doesn't exist in `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/`

For Linux create `setenv.sh` and add

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xmx2048m"
```

For Windows create `setenv.bat` and add

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xmx2048m
```

Change the Xmx value to your needs.